# How to ignore a folder to compile in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, gulp, sbt, playframework-2.4

I have a `node_modules` folder which resides in `public` folder it contains lot of files which is causing my localhost:9000 to keep on loading for hours 
I want to ignore this folder in play framework 
according to this question [Include/Exclude asset folder/directory in sbt/play-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000681/include-exclude-asset-folder-directory-in-sbt-play-framework/37356485)

I have followed the steps:
build.sbt

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filterNot { case (_, name) =>
      name.startsWith("public\\node_modules")
}}

import play.sbt.PlayImport.PlayKeys.playRunHooks
    lazy val gulpDirectory = baseDirectory {
        _ / "admin-panel"//what should i write here? 
    } 
excludeFilter := HiddenFileFilter -- ".tmp"

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets <+= gulpDirectory { _ / "dist"}

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets <+= gulpDirectory { _ / ".tmp"}

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets <+= gulpDirectory { _ / "bower_components"}

//this is for development environment
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets <+= gulpDirectory { _ / "src" / "app"}    
playRunHooks <+= gulpDirectory.map(path => Gulp(path))
```

and project/Gulp.scala

```
import play.sbt.PlayRunHook
import sbt._

import java.net.InetSocketAddress

object Gulp {
    def apply(base: File): PlayRunHook = {

        object GulpProcess extends PlayRunHook {

            val gulpFile = "gulpfile.js"
            var process: Option[Process] = None

            override def beforeStarted(): Unit = {
                if (isWindows) {
                    Process("cmd /c gulp build", base).run
                } else {
                    Process("gulp build", base).run
                }
            }

            override def afterStarted(addr: InetSocketAddress): Unit = {
                if (isWindows) {
                    Some(Process("cmd /c gulp serve", base).run)
                } else {
                    Some(Process("gulp serve", base).run)
                }
            }

            override def afterStopped(): Unit = {
                process.map(p => p.destroy())
                process = None
            }

            private def isWindows: Boolean = {
                System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")
            }
        }

        GulpProcess
    }
}
```

I have two questions 
first is `node_modules` is located at `home/user/git/testproject/public/node_module`
what should I write instead to `admin-panel` in `build.sbt`
I have tried to write `public`

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport.PlayKeys.playRunHooks
lazy val gulpDirectory = baseDirectory {
    _ / "public"
}
```

But I am getting this exception

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gulp" (in directory "home/user/git/testproject/public"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last testproject/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (arteciate/compile:run) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gulp" (in directory "/home/user/git/testproject/public"): error=2, No such file or directory
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 4, 2017 7:44:14 PM
```

Second if there is another method to ignore `node_modules` folder please help because I am unable to `debug`, `test`, `run` my project. 
I am using `play 2.4`

**Edit**
I am using play 2.4 My play app was working fine then I needed to install some UI components like `graunt` `bower` `ruby` `compass` after installing these components when I do activator run after `reload` `clean` `compile` and hit localhost:9000 it takes almost an hour or more to load the page

Comment: why is node_modules in public and not in the root?

Comment: i do not know i have installed graunt bower ruby compass ui components

Answer (score 1):

Since the `node_modules` folder contains only `Node.js` modules that don't need to be scanned and compiled by `sbt`, you can exclude completely that folder in the `build.sbt`

```scala
excludeFilter := {
    val public = (baseDirectory.value / "public" / "node_modules").getCanonicalPath
    new SimpleFileFilter(_.getCanonicalPath startsWith public)
}
```

To compile the `Node.js` front-end part of your application you have to use the dedicated `gulp build` command instead of using the `Gulp.scala` class.

```html
$ cd /home/user/git/testproject/public/
/home/user/git/testproject/public$ gulp build
```

If some `Node.js` dependency in `node_modules` still needs to be installed, before running `gulp build` execute the following command:

```html
$ cd /home/user/git/testproject/public/
/home/user/git/testproject/public$ npm install
```

If some `Node.js` dependency in `node_modules` is out of date, before running `gulp build` execute the following command:

```html
$ cd /home/user/git/testproject/public/
/home/user/git/testproject/public$ npm update
```